# undefined method `raise_on_missing_translations=' for class ActionView::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When upgrading from rails 6.0.3.6 to rails 7.0.8 I got:

```
undefined method `raise_on_missing_translations=' for class ActionView::Base
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use the new way:

```
-  config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
+  config.i18n.raise_on_missing_translations = true
```